# No logro descargar o visualizar el pdf REACT front Y LARAVEL api

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs

Hola comienzo explicando yo antes usaba un get simple sin headers para descargar los pdf esto paso a cambiar y se aplicaron los correspondientes headers y una vez se aplicaron la aplicacion dejo de funcionar. probe usar dos metodos de descarga en php:

```
 return response()->download($fichero);
```

y

```
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename(date("d-m-Y").".pdf").'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fichero));
```

Ninguno de los dos funcionaron entonces me quede sin opciones por el lado de back entonces me puse a buscar como cambiarlo en front

en un principio probamos sin el bload vimo en internet que necesita el blood entonces empezamos a utilizarlo y llegamos a un punto donde descarga el pdf pero vacio completamentamente en blanco. este es el codigo:

```
async function pruebaAxios() {

    echo({ title: "Etamos en axios", message: "Prueba Axios", type: "error" })

    let config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://apibanktestwaf.trenesargentinos.gob.ar/api/auth/usuarios/abmtest3/5',
      resposeType: 'blob',
      headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': !!sessionStorage.getItem("access_token") ? ${sessionStorage.getItem("token_type")} ${sessionStorage.getItem("access_token")} : ${localStorage.getItem("token_type")} ${localStorage.getItem("access_token")},
        'ApiKey': API_KEY,
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
      }
    };

    axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
        echo({ title: "Respuesta desde axios", message: response, type: "error" })
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data],  {type: "aplication/pdf"}));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.download = 'archivo.pdf';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        // setLinkAxios(url)
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        echo({ title: "Error", message: error.response.data, type: "error" })
        console.log(error);
  });
  }
```

Y esta es la llamada por front a esa llamada a la api que vimos arriba:

```
      <div>
        <button className='btn btn-danger' onClick={()=>pruebaAxios()}>Prueba de axios</button>
      </div>
```